# Best method to conduct retrospective meeting for a MVP?

Tags: product-owner, retrospective, business-analyst

### Scenario

As we know, a Sprint Retrospective is a meeting held at the end of an iteration to evaluate the Scrum Team's performance, what happened in the iteration and identify actions for improvement going forward. Suppose we are working on a minimum viable product (MVP) to be launched shortly. The product is not launched in the market and is awaiting customer feedback. So it is very essential to evaluate the Sprint items rigorously in a meeting. Basically, I want to conduct the best and most efficient retro meeting.

Comment: VTC as too broad. Take a look at this, though: https://martinfowler.com/articles/itsNotJustStandingUp.html

Comment: The above links described about the daily stand up meeting. I would like to know the suitable method to conduct retrospective meeting for a MVP.

Comment: Oh, misread, sorry. Anyway, you should be able to just search for "Scrum Retrospective Tips". If you want help from PMSE, you'll probably need to narrow the scope of your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described context does give much specifics for the retrospective. As you don't have customer feedback, the retrospective should probably focus on the team interworking. It can be any format from [benlinders.com/exercises](https://www.benlinders.com/exercises). If you give me more info, then I can pinpoint you to specific exercises that might be suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Basically i am trying to understand the features implemented in each sprint is perfect and would like to prove with some data with the help of retrospective meeting. 
For example : We have implemented a new report "Performance report" to evaluate the portfolio return and performance of all the clients. So i would like to explain or prove to the external party with some date that the report satisfies the design, usability, and other technical factors. How this can be proved in the retrospective meeting ?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. What you are trying to do makes a lot of sense, certainly within a Lean Startup approach when you're creating an MVP. But I don't think the retrospective would be the right meeting to do this, as the main purpose of the retro is to learn and improve as a team, not to improve the product (see https://www.benlinders.com/2013/whats-an-agile-retrospective-and-why-would-you-do-it/). Also the retrospective focus is internal, where your focus is (for very good reasons) externally on the product and business value.

Comment: @JithinAntony: What you describe here sounds more like a product demonstration to the external party.

Comment: It's more than/different from a product demo. The aim of the demo is to get feedback, but if I'm not mistaken then he wants to validate the MVP, closing the build-measure-learn loop, right?

Answer (score 0):

MVP is to bring product to customer's table quicker to bring more understanding of what customer has conceptualized and to get the alignment of feels & thoughts against the product.  In sprint retrospection, you can discuss what went good and what can be improved to bring more stories to the delivery.

Post customer feedback, one can fine tune definitions of 'what' needs to be delivered.

But, sprint retrospection can help in fine tuning 'how' part of delivery.